# Cannot resolve constructor on Typeface error

Tags: java, android

Apologies if this seems obvious. I want to set the font of my alert dialog title to match a `.ttf` file using `Spannable` String. However I am retrieving a cannot resolve constructor

> (TypefaceSpan(android.graphics.'Typeface')) error.

Code:

```
Typeface customFont;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/pacifico_regular.ttf");

    ...

    questionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 SpannableString title = new SpannableString("HOW TO USE THE APP");
                 title.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(customFont),
                            0, title.length(), 
                 Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
}
```

Comment: have you checked whether that class has such a constructor?

Comment: Which API Level do you use? The constructor you needed was introduced in level 28

Comment: I beleive it's API level 22. In that case what is the best way to set the font for the title only? I want the dialog text to be san serif so I set that in the xml but for the title I want it to be et to customFont

Comment: added more code in question if that makes it easier